# flatbuffer from TS to C++ not working

Tags: c++, typescript, flatbuffers

I have a flatbuffer schema for a [message](https://github.com/gabyx/ExecutionGraph/blob/devGUI/gui/executionGraphGUI/messages/schemas/GraphManipulationMessages.fbs):

```
table NodeConstructionInfo {
    type:string (id: 0, required);          
    name:string (id: 1, required);         
}

table AddNodeRequest {
    graphId:string (id:0, required);            
    node:NodeConstructionInfo (id:1, required);
}
```

which I construct (write) in TypeScript and receive (read) in C++:

```
let builder = new flatbuffers.Builder(356);
let offGraphId = builder.createString("2992ebff-c950-4184-8876-5fe6ac029aa5");
let offType = builder.createString("MySuperDuperNode");
let offName = builder.createString("DummyNode");

sz.NodeConstructionInfo.startNodeConstructionInfo(builder);
sz.NodeConstructionInfo.addName(builder, offName);
sz.NodeConstructionInfo.addType(builder, offType);
let off = sz.NodeConstructionInfo.endNodeConstructionInfo(builder);

sz.AddNodeRequest.startAddNodeRequest(builder);
sz.AddNodeRequest.addGraphId(builder, offGraphId);
sz.AddNodeRequest.addNode(builder, off);
off = sz.AddNodeRequest.endAddNodeRequest(builder);
builder.finish(off);

let requestPayload = builder.asUint8Array();
```

In C++ I receive the 356 bytes (`requestPayload`) and try to verify it by doing

```
flatbuffers::Verifier v(buffer.getData(), buffer.getSize());
v.VerifyBuffer<AddNodeRequest>();
```

which always fails in `<flatbuffers/flatbuffers.h>` at:

```
template<typename T>
bool VerifyBufferFromStart(const char *identifier, const uint8_t *start) 
{
   ...
   // Call T::Verify, which must be in the generated code for this type.
   auto o = VerifyOffset(start); <--- HERE (the first read flatbuffers::uoffset_t should not be 0 (don't know why)?)
   ...
}
```

Am I missing some important detail? 
The buffer looks like

```
PostData received: 

'\x00,\x00,\x00,\x00,\x00,\x00,\x00,\x00,\x00,\x00,\x00,\x00,\x00,\x00,\x00,\x00,\x00,
\x00,\x00,\x00,\x00,\x00,\x00,\x00,\x00,\x00,\x00,\x00,\x00,\x00,\x00,\x00,\x00,\x00,\x00,\x00,\x00,\x00,
\x00,\x00,\x00,\x00,\x00,\x00,\x00,\x00,\x00,\x00,\x00,\x00,\x00,\x00,\x00,\x00,\x00,\x00,\x00,\x00,\x00,
\x00,\x00,\x00,\x00,\x00,\x00,\x00,\x00,\x00,\x00,\x00,\x00,\x00,\x00,\x00,\x00,\x00,\x00,\x00,\x00,\x00,
\x00,\x00,\x00,\x00,\x00,\x00,\x00,\x00,\x00,\x00,\x00,\x00,\x00,\x00,\x00,\x00,\x00,\x00,\x00,\x00,\x00,
\x00,\x00,\x00,\x00,\x00,\x00,\x00,\x00,\x00,\x00,\x00,\x00,\x00,\x00,\x00,\x00,\x00,\x00,\x00,\x00,\x00,
\x00,\x00,\x00,\x00,\x00,\x00,\x00,\x00,\x00,\x00,\x00,\x00,\x00,\x00,\x00,\x00,\x00,\x00,\x00,\x00,\x00,
\x00,\x00,\x00,\x00,\x00,\x00,\x00,\x00,\x00,\x00,\x00,\x00,\x00,\x00,\x00,\x00,\x00,\x00,\x00,\x00,\x00,
\x00,\x00,\x00,\x00,\x00,\x00,\x00,\x00,\x00,\x00,\x00,\x00,\x00,\x00,\x00,\x00,\x00,\x00,\x00,\x00,\x00,
\x00,\x00,\x00,\x00,\x00,\x00,\x00,\x00,\x00,\x00,\x00,\x00,\x00,\x00,\x00,\x00,\x00,\x00,\x00,\x00,\x00,
\x00,\x00,\x00,\x00,\x00,\x00,\x00,\x00,\x00,\x00,\x00,\x00,\x00,\x00,\x00,\x00,\x00,\x00,\x00,\x00,\x00,
\x00,\f,\x00,\x00,\x00,\b,\x00,\f,\x00,\b,\x00,\x04,\x00,\b,\x00,\x00,\x00,\x10,\x00,\x00,\x00,@,\x00,\x00,
\x00,\b,\x00,\f,\x00,\x04,\x00,\b,\x00,\b,\x00,\x00,\x00, ,\x00,\x00,\x00,\x04,\x00,\x00,\x00,\x10,\x00,\x00,
\x00,M,y,S,u,p,e,r,D,u,p,e,r,N,o,d,e,\x00,\x00,\x00,\x00,\t,\x00,\x00,\x00,D,u,m,m,y,N,o,d,e,
\x00,\x00,\x00,$,\x00,\x00,\x00,2,9,9,2,e,b,f,f,-,c,9,5,0,-,4,1,8,4,-,8,8,7,6,-,5,f,e,6,a,c,0,2,9,a,a,5,
\x00,\x00,\x00,\x00
```

Reading messages in TypeScript written from C++ works... (?)
**flatbuffer version 1.9.0**

Answer (score 1):

As your buffer dump shows, the problem is that it contains a lot of leading zeros. A FlatBuffer while being constructed actually may contain leading zeroes (since it is being constructed in a larger buffer backwards), but `asUint8Array` normally takes care of trimming that down to just the array you need. So either you're not actually using `asUint8Array` in your actual code, or the zeroes are being pre-pended by some other code.

Comment: Thanks, thats what I was wondering as well, why its not trimmed down?
I will have a look into this... strange

Comment: I found the source of my problem, I convert to ArrayBuffer to send it with the angular `HttpClient.post` method which sends the whole buffer which is kind of wrong...

Comment: Your buffer actually starts at the first non-zero byte, \f (which is 12). In TS, break the debugger next to `asUint8Array`, and check the fields of `builder.bb`. `position should be non-zero in your case. The size of the array should be a lot less than `356`.

Comment: Ah.. you mean it ignores the start of the slice and just uses the whole underlying buffer? can you show the code where this happens?

Comment: Yes exactly: 
``data = payload.buffer as ArrayBuffer;``

Comment: ``this.httpClient.post(url, data, { responseType: 'arraybuffer', headers: new HttpHeaders({ 'Content-Type': this.binaryMimeType }) })``

Comment: I dont know yet how to convert (without a stupid copy!) to a sliced type (ArrayBuffer) which is sendable with the post method...?

Comment: I don't know either since I don't use JS, but accessing the underlying buffer like that is still an error.. frankly it should be private

Answer (score 0):

The problem is the position and how data is sent in the post. The buffer must be sliced to the position specified in ByteBuffer and the post must be send like a Blob.

```
builder.finish(end);
var buffer: flatbuffers.ByteBuffer = builder.dataBuffer();
var data: Uint8Array = buffer.bytes().slice(buffer.position());
this.http.post(environment.apiRoot + "hello", new Blob([data])).subscribe(
      () => {},
      (error) => {}
    );
```